# Export App Inventor UI to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, app-inventor

I'm really new to android development, and now I'm doing a group project developing an android application and I'm in charge of user interface. My teammates are using eclipse to write code and I'm using App Inventor to design the UI. My question is, how do I export the UI to eclipse? or can I?

Comment: Why not prototype on Inventor, then someone can quickly do the work in Eclipse to make it available.

Answer (score 4):

http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/userfaq.html

> **Can I develop in App Inventor and export the source code to Eclipse or some other IDE to work on it further?**
>
> No, App Inventor does not generate Java source code.

If you want a dirty hack, create the apk with app inventor, and use APKManager to extract all the xml files from the res folder. You can add then those to the Eclipse project.

[APKManager thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695701)

Answer (score 1):

A version of App inventor is being worked on that can export directly to java files and even an Eclipse project.

Check it out here:

https://appinventortojava.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

The last time that I checked, you cannot export it.  The Android plugin for Eclipse does give you a (somewhat unreliable) drag-and-drop interface for the UI layout.  You will learn a lot more about Android and programming if you do all the work in Eclipse, too.